# How to differentiate between 'loose' and 'lose'

Tags: word-choice, mnemonic

Does anyone have a good way of remembering when to choose *lose* instead of *loose*?

I often find myself mistakenly using *loose* in emails and such when I really mean *lose* (which, in my mind, should be pronounced *loss*).

Comment: clarification: by "should be pronounced _loss_" do you mean "should rhyme with _dose_" or "should rhyme with _boss_"? Wouldn't a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word spelled _lose_ be to rhyme with _dose_?

Comment: @jp2c Great question!  What the world really needs is a Mnemonic for "brought/bought."  I am physically ill when people accidentally use "bought" when they mean "brought"!  :)

Comment: @nohat: No, I mean that every time I encounter the word *lose*, I say *loss* in my mind. *Lose* should have the same mnemonic as *close* whereas *loose* should rhyme with *Jews* (no religious offenses intended).

Comment: Your mind is pronouncing *lose* the wrong way. *Lose* rhymes with *clues*, not with *close*.

Comment: Yes, I just need a good way to remember that when it comes to my emails. :)

Comment: To understand what the better answer is, we should need to know which is your first language. Basing on that, the answer could change.

Comment: @JoeBlow - why do you need a mnemonic?  "Bring" contains an R, "buy" does not; and the same is true in the past tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One [suggestion for remembering lose](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/lose.html) is to pronounce the word out loud:

> If it has a voiced Z sound, then it’s “lose.” If it has a hissy S sound, then it’s “loose.”

Of course, this might not help if you think of *loss* when you see *lose*.

Some other [suggestions for remembering lose](http://www.ross.net/notes/loose.shtml) rely on spelling:

> One way to remember the difference between the two words is to think that "lose has lost an 'o'".

or further [mnemonics and a lose-loose quiz here](http://homepage.smc.edu/quizzes/cheney_joyce/looselose.html):

> Loose with its two "o's" should remind you that there is too much space so something is "loose" as in a pair of loose (or roomy) pants.

I agree with @kiamlaluno, though: You hardly ever want to use "loose" as a verb in modern writing. If you intentionally use "loose," it's usually as an adjective: "My shoelace is coming untied; it's loose." If you can remember to check whether you're trying to use the word as a verb, that's probably easier than any of these mnemonics.

Comment: I agree that it's rare to see it as a verb, but it is valid in that form: "to loose" is synonymous with "to release" or "to let loose". It was common in archery before powder weapons were developed; "firing" an arrow wouldn't make sense until you'd become used to "firing" a firearm.

Answer (score 6):

A noose could be loose, I guess. Bonus if you think of "Gallow's Pole".
Suggested poem:

> "If the noose is loose you win. Otherwise, you lose".

Comment: Make a mnemonic from it:  _If your noose is loose, you win; otherwise you lose._

Comment: Eh, "the noose is loose" is enough of a mnemonic in this case where you have only a binary choice. But your suggestion is good.

Comment: Try: *A loose noose is whose to lose?*

Answer (score 2):

As verb, *loose* means

- set free, release
- untie, unfasten
- relax one's grip

If the verb you are using doesn't have one of those meaning, then you are probably using *lose*.

> I am losing the game. (It's not *I am loosing the game*.)
>   I have lost appetite. (It's not *I have loosen appetite*.)
>   The ropes were loosed. (Differently, it would mean you had some ropes that you don't find anymore.)

Comment: The questioner is looking for a fun **Mnemonic reminder** .. not a definition.

Comment: @Joe Blow The OP asked for a way to remember which word to use; he didn't write anything about a fun mnemonic reminder.

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  Well, it's true the OP didn't specifically ask for *fun*.  But he asked for a *mnemonic*, and basically just going over the definitions and parts of speech are not likely to be a net gain in ease of remembering.

Comment: @John Y Actually, the OP asked for an [helper](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/29847/1). I took he meant a help on remembering when to use _loose_ and _lose_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, exactly, and my point is that what you have offered is, in my opinion, not particularly easy to remember for someone who is having trouble with those two words.

Comment: @John Y I am not sure that "if it's loose you will lose it" helps who keeps to write _loose_ instead of _lose_. If the question were asked from somebody who doesn't speak English as first language, it would help to associate the words to the words in his native language. Not knowing that, the only thing that can help to remember which word to use is to remember the meaning of that word.

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  I don't know that my answer is better than yours.  I did not downvote your answer.  But the OP clearly *knows* the meanings of the words.  He didn't ask "what's the difference between *lose* and *loose*?"; he asked "how do I overcome my crazy instinct to mess these words up?".  The point of a mnemonic is to try a "side route", so to speak.  The straightforward path is not working for him.

Comment: @John Y Without knowing the first language of who is asking the question, I would take he doesn't speak English. In that case, your tip is less useful than the tip of remembering the meaning of a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, I don't know of any *quick* mnemonics.  I think most people are either just very good at these words, and don't need any special tricks; or they are perennially having trouble.

I assume you know the difference when you hear them, right?  So you somehow have to remember that *loose* both looks like **and** rhymes with *goose*, *moose*, and *noose*.  Interestingly (and unfortunately), I can't think of anything *lose* both looks like and rhymes with, but probably best is to try to associate it with *hose* and *nose*, to at least get the 'z' sound.

Yeah, this isn't really an on-the-spot mnemonic; more of something to just practice and try to train yourself with.  Hopefully it's "catchier" than straight-up memorization of the two words, at least.

Hmm... still kind of on the weak side, but does it help to see them both in a single (vaguely plausible) sentence?  Like

> Make sure to tie it real tight,
>   because if it's *loose*, you'll *lose*
>   it.

Um, that's all I got.

Answer (score 1):

loose is loose and hence has two o's.

lose has lost an o and hence is just lose!

Answer (score 1):

Loose has two Os to get lost in, when you Lose an O, the items go.